# CollectionViewSource is filtered?

Tags: wpf, filtering, collectionviewsource

What's the easiest way to know if the view is currently filtered or not? I want a clearAll type of command that is only is displayed when there is something to clear.

Thanks!
Berryl

Comment: I can just check to see if the View.Filter == null apparently.

Comment: true, unless you set a filter that did nothing.

Comment: @John Gardner. Hi, John, forgot about this one. I wound up checking all the default values for the filter, although if I was going to do it now, it might be as simple as checking to see if the view count is less than the source count. If you want to answer this I'd be happy to close it out tho. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to compare the count of items in the View with the count of items in the source collection.  If they are not the same, the view is filtered.